# javascript and jquery script tags in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a spot of trouble with bootstrap. I started having problems with the links in the [nav](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs) component not being clickable. The links were fine when typed into the browser, but not when clicked.

I rearranged the order of the script tags at the bottom of the body so the link to jQuery in my Django static directory came first and the links became 'clickable', although it broke other functionality like a menu drop-down and an accordion, which no longer opens.

I've tried moving the script tags into the  section, switching them back; tried the development version of jQuery.... nothing seems to work.

What's going on? How can I get both the links active and the javascript functionality to work.

```
  <head>
        {% block head %}
        # ...
        # ...

        {% load static %}

            <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

            <style type="text/css">
              body {
                padding-top: 60px;
                padding-bottom: 40px;
              }
            </style>
            <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-responsive.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        {% endblock head %}

   </head>

   <body id="body">
          {% block body %} 

           #.....
           #.....

            <!-- Le javascript
            ================================================== -->
            <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

            <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js' %}"></script>
            <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>


          {% endblock body %}  
  </body>
```

Comment: Don't you need to put quotes around those urls?

Comment: I now have the tags in quotes and single quotes around the path within the tag and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and chin strokng, I realised that in the template I was calling from my view, I had the following:

```
  {% for group in class_groups %}
    <li><a data-toggle=**"tab"** href="{% url 'subnav' sub_slug=subj class_grp_slug=group.group_name %}">{{ group.group_name }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
```

when it should actually have been:

```
  {% for group in class_groups %}
    <li><a data-toggle=**"tabs"** href="{% url 'subnav' sub_slug=subj class_grp_slug=group.group_name %}">{{ group.group_name }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
```

Both the dropdown and the nav-tab are working now.